# Plots starting at different location on x-axis

Tags: matplotlib, plot, graph, graphics

I am trying to plot a series of functions starting at different location on the x-axis. I'm fine with plotting them starting at the origin but varying location is causing trouble with these iteration. for instance:

```
x = [2,4,8, ..., Max]

y1=x**2 + 4
y2=x**2 + 4
...
y_m=x**2 + 4
```

Each plotted between:

```
[0, Max], [2, Max], [8, Max], .... [x_n-1, Max]
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, plotted

Comment: So they will all lie on top of each other, but  the last one will consist only of a small segment?

Comment: yes @ImportanceOfBeingErnest .. that is correct. and the last one will have a small segment. that is correct

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest We call it left truncation. all these plots are left-truncated

Comment: I think it would have helped if you had mentionned the notion 'truncate' in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to plot this left truncated function set, you may iterate over the starting index of an array slice, i.e. `x[i:]`, which would select the complete list for `i==0` and reduce the number of elements to be taken into account by one in succesive loop steps.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(2,16,2)
f = lambda x: x**2 + 4

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(len(x)-1):
    ax.plot(x[i:], f(x[i:]), lw=2,label="Starting at {}".format(x[i]))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnes. It works separetly but when trying to incorporate in my my code it says, `ValueError: Image size of 729x10277342 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.` .. do you know how I can reduce the figure size?

Comment: What image are you talking about? This is in any case independent on the figure size, but still, there is no image in the question and I have no idea what other code you try to use. I really sounds like this is a completely different problem, so try to build a [mcve] of the new issue (which should not depend on those truncated functions, I would guess) and ask a new, clear question about it.